# Matrix preallocation - MATLAB

Tags: performance, matlab

I have the following code:

```
clear; clc;

a = [1,2,3,4,3];

b = zeros(1,5);
for i = 1:4
    for j = i+1:5
        if a(i) == a(j)
            b = [b,i];
        end
    end
end
b
```

`b` is an array that results from concatenating elements inside the double `for` loop. Even though I declare the array `b = zeros(1,5)`, `MATLAB` warns me that `b` needs to be preallocated. How should I modify the code, so  `MATLAB` stops warning me for preallocation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the concatenation step `b = [b, i]` will *append* `i` to `b` so you're just puting number after your zeros matrix. What you want is to assign to a specific element of `b` like `b(???)=i`, that `???` needs to go in order so it's easiest to just keep a separate counter variable.

```
clear; clc;

a = [1,2,3,4,3];

b = zeros(1,5);
counter = 1;
for i = 1:4
    for j = i+1:5
        if a(i) == a(j)
            b(counter) = i;
            counter = counter + 1;
        end
    end
end

b
```

Note that you would need to over allocated `b` in this example because you don't actually know upfront how many elements it will have in the end, and if your example really is this simple then I would probably just ignore the warning in this case unless you're finding that your code is slow

Answer (score 2):

Try the following. You have preallocated the array correctly, but after pre-allocating you are again try to dynamically expand it by the statement b=[b,i]; what this will do is concatenate new elements after the 5 zeros.

```
clear; clc;    
a = [1,2,3,4,3];
b = zeros(1,5);
b_idx=0;
for i = 1:4
    for j = i+1:5
        if a(i) == a(j)
            b_idx = b_idx+1;
            b(b_idx) = i;
        end
    end
end
disp(b);
```